# App/Web Part drop down menu is barely visible

Tags: web-part

Hi I went to add a new web part to one of my pages and I encountered a weird error of some kind. The drop-down that appears when you click web part (like Business Data, Filter, Blog, etc.) is barely visible almost like it's behind the main page. I can click on App part and it changes but I can't click on any of the links.

Anyone ever seen this? I've rebooted but the same after and I've tried with multiple web browsers.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Amal reverting to the previous master page fixed the issue. Now I just need to figure out how to get around my original issue and not break it again.

Comment: Cool. I have posted it as an answer. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This is a Style Issue happened by overriding Microsoft Style. I think the source of this is either Master Page or Page Layout.

Check the Master Page and see if that helps.